# C Segmentation fault error on print

Tags: c, string, printf, fault

In the following code with the printf() statement I get a segmentation fault: 11. Without it I do not get any of errors but I want to be able to see the correct values are in the newstring value. How do I go about doing this?

```
  char* newstring;
  for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    printf("value %d\n", tempfullstring[i]);
    if (tempfullstring[i]>=97 && tempfullstring[i] <=122)
    {
      char value = tempfullstring[i];
      newstring += value;
    }
  }
  printf("The new string is %s", newstrng);
  return 0;
```

Comment: Which printf() line that has the problem? What is the content of tempfullstring? Can you give us more *useful* code?

Comment: In your printf statement, newstring is misspelled ("newstrng"). I'm not sure if this was a typing error local to your post, or if it mirrors your actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a misunderstanding of how C strings work:

- They do *not* get initialized on declaration (so `char* newstring;` must be assigned separately, or you get undefined behavior)
- They cannot be concatenated with a `+=` operator (so `newstring += value;` is invalid)
- The space for C strings needs to be managed explicitly (so you would either need to allocate your `newstring` in the automatic storage area, or add a `free` at the end).

The easiest way of fixing your program is to guess how long the `newstring` is going to be, and use `strcat` to append data to it:

```
char newstring[1000]; // some max length
newstring[0] = '\0';  // make it an empty string
...
strcat(newstring, value); // instead of newstring += value
```

Comment: `newstring += value` is valid, it just does not do what the OP thinks it does.

Comment: @WilliamPursell That's why I said that it does not concatenate, as opposed to calling it invalid :)

Answer (score 1):

```
newstring += value
```

You are appending to a string in an illegal way, what you are actually doing is changing an uninitialized pointer, **so you are moving an changing address to another invalid address instead**.

You should, first of all, have some room in which you are going to store the new string such with

```
char newstring[64];
```

and then append a character by doing

```
newstring[j] = tempfullstring[i];
```

This won't append the NUL terminating character through, you will have to add it to the end manually or use a different approach (such as using `strncat` and append directly from the original string:

```
strncat(newstring+j, tempfullstring+i, 1);
```

Comment: Yes, it has to, infact in the `strncat` approach I used `i` and `j`

Answer (score 1):

this is the code you'll want to make this work.

```
 char* newstring = malloc (sizeof(char)*len+1);   // this will be worst case (all are >=97 o <=122
    int j=0;
      for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
      {
        printf("value %d\n", tempfullstring[i]);
        if (tempfullstring[i]>=97 && tempfullstring[i] <=122)
        {
          char value = tempfullstring[i];
          newstring[j]= value;
          j++;
        }
      }
      newstring[j]='\0';
      printf("The new string is %s", newstrng);
      return 0;
```